# API Request Assistance

Tags: rest

I'm new to playing around with calling third party REST API's.

I have an API which requires an ID (/sites/{id}/. As I don't know the ID off the top of my head and would like to query multiple ID's, is there anyway to wildcard this ID for it to run through and check for instance ID's 1 through to 10? Or is this more of a python integration?

Comment: Q:  is there anyway to wildcard this ID for it to run through and check for instance ID's 1 through to 10?  A: That depends entirely on the API.  In all likelihood: "No".

Comment: An API endpoint such as `sites/id` is likely expecting a single id in order for it to get the specified resource.  Programmatically, on your end you can pass through a single dynamic value using whichever programming/scripting language you use, but it is likely the API is expecting a single id.  If it is appropriate/safe/secure to do so, if you can share which public API you are working with, perhaps that would provide others with more context.

Comment: Thanks for your response, the specific API i'm looking at is https://help.rapid7.com/insightvm/en-us/api/index.html#operation/getSiteScanTemplate

I specifcally want to be able to query multiple sites to get this information back, but can't seem to find a way without entering the ID manually

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, if an API happens to have a parameter "id", whether or not you can scan for all available IDs (or any ID between 1 and 10) depends entirely on the API.

In your case, the API (for help.rapid7.com) is well documented.  It appears to have an endpoint to "list sites", which should give you what you're looking for:

> https://help.rapid7.com/insightvm/en-us/api/index.html#operation/getSites
>
> ```
> Sites
> GET /api/3/sites
> Server URL
>
> https://help.rapid7.com/api/3/sites
> Retrieves a paged resource of accessible sites.
>
>
> PARAMETERS
> Query Parameters
> * page  integer <int32>
>   Default: 0
>   The index of the page (zero-based) to retrieve.
>
> * size  integer <int32>
>   Default: 10
>   The number of records per page to retrieve.
>
> * sort    
>   Multiple query params of string
>   The criteria to sort the records by, in the format: 
>     property[,ASC|DESC]. 
>   The default sort order is  ascending.
>   Multiple sort criteria can be specified using multiple sort query parameters.
> ```

You would probably want to do the following:

- Call  `/api/3/sites` (with a filter) to get a list of sites you're interested in, then
- Make successive calls to `/sites/{id}/` for each site in the list you want detailed information about.

Comment: Thanks, sorry getting used to this. Cheers